# Understanding php logic on conditionals - return true understanding

Tags: php

The point is to validate, only when,

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['enabled']
```

It's equal to one. So, if `$this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1`, validate.

I was expecting that this peace of code, would do the job:

```
public function compareDates() {
   if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1) {
      return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
   }
}
```

However it seems that that doesn't work as I expected. Instead, it gets always validated, regardless the value of `$this->data[$this->alias]['enabled']`

This code, however, seems to do the job just fine:

```
public function compareDates() {
    if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] != 1) return true; // we don't want to check
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
}
```

What is, in your understanding, the meaning of "we don't want to check"? 
Why: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1)` is not enough?

Can anyone care to explain?

***Update:***

If I do:

```
public function compareDates() 
{
  if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === "1") {
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

It works as well. My question is:

**Why do I need to explicitly declare the `return true`?;**

Comment: In the first case, what do you expect to be returned if `..['enabled'] != 1`?

Comment: @kingkero I would expect to see returned `$this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];` for every cases where there aren't any string OR integer `1`. But I guess am I seeing that wrong... :(

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a simple comparison (`==`) so PHP is looking for "truthy" statements. So ANY value that is not "falsey" will evaluate your statement (i.e. `0`, `false`, empty strings, `NULL`). You can find a complete list [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

The best way around this is to use equivalency to ensure it's the exact value you want

```
if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === 1)
```

That will force PHP to look for an integer of `1`. Be aware, though, that your value MUST be the same. In other words

```
if('1' === 1)
```

Is always false because string `1` is not the same as integer `1`

Comment: I was more or less aware of the difference between `==` and `===`, but the thing is, I'm not sure if the script in questios does actually return an integer or a string. I will check it. But, please have patience: If I do: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === 1)` it will return true, if and only if, the `1` is an integer. If however, I do: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] == 1)`it will return true, regardless if you have the string '1' or any other string? - thanks again.

Comment: The value returned on `enabled` is a string. But if I do: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === '1')` - I still get always true (I guess)... even if a string ´0´ exists instead... :s

Comment: Can you change your script to use true booleans like `true` and `false`? It's strange that equivalency doesn't work.

Comment: do you mean to change the `enable` return value? I can do that, but, for some reason, the `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] != 1) return true;` works. And that's what I'm trying to understand why. So, if I change that script to true of false, if may, perhaps, work, as it works right now with the `return true` explicitly declared, but, my point is to understand why is that. :)

Comment: `if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] != 1) return true;` if this is the case, the data comparison will not work. However, notice that we have `1` and not `"1"`, while I can assure (via var_dump), that the value returned is a string and NOT an integer.

Comment: That would work because PHP ignores the data types in that case. Equivalency, or `===`, forces PHP to convert them to the same data type first.

Comment: I've updated my question. I tested with another code sample, using equivalency. And I got some results. Still, I don't understand why we need to explicitly declare a `return true` - it seems that `return true` will force us to exiting the function somehow...?

Comment: I've clear up this mess question and created a new one regarding this understanding problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826880/why-do-we-need-the-return-true-on-this-method