# Why do we need the "return true" on this method?

Tags: php

This data comparison should only occur, when `enable` has the string 1.

```
public function compareDates() 
{
  if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === "1") {
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I don't state the `return true` on the else clause, the compareDates() will never "exit", regardless of the value being "1" or "bla bla".

Why is that?

Comment: If you don't put `return true`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, the function will "exit" nonetheless, meaning the code will proceed anyway, it won't stop the execution.

Comment: If your function returns mixed results, make sure that you explicitly document what it can return, that way any conditionals making use of it can properly compare based on datatype

Comment: Argh! :s I got confused: why `return true` means "exit function execution", and `return false` doesn't? I mean, should `return` regardless of the value, be the end of the line for that function execution? I clearly missing some core concepts. Please advice.

Comment: `true` or `false` are just values. Return X means: "the code should stop here, back to who call it and say X"

Comment: But if I change `return true` to `return false` on that else clause, the methods keeps being called... ?

Comment: keep in mind that return false returns BOOLEAN false. Even though 0 the int can be used to represent false, you should still document exactly what is returned. See the docs for strpos regarding what it returns, I think it may apply to your case. As far as it not "exiting" the function, return should always pop the function off the call stack and send the value back to the caller, so I'm not sure what's going on there. Could be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @MEM Of course it keep on being called. Imagine the logic saying `if (compareDates()) { //Do something }` and we want this to happen if it's not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Argh! :s I got confused: why return true means "exit function
>   execution", and return false doesn't? I mean, should return regardless
>   of the value, be the end of the line for that function execution? I
>   clearly missing some core concepts. Please advice.
>
> ...But if I change return true to return false on that else clause,
>   the methods keeps being called"

return does return regardless of the value so you are correct in your assumption there.

it seems like your issue probably lies in the function that is calling compareDates().  You say that the method "keeps being called", is compareDates() being called within a loop perhaps?
you will want to double check to make sure that you are correctly handling the return value of compareDates() in the calling function.

p.s. (on the issue of omitting the return statement from a function)

from http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

> "If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned."

** Updated **

Now that we know you are using the Cake Framework.

from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html <-- all about cake framework data-validation here

[Section: Adding your own Validation Methods]

> "The method should return true if the value is valid. If the
>   validation failed, return false. The other valid return value are
>   strings which will be shown as the error message. Returning a string
>   means the validation failed. "

This means that your firstPageEnterDate field will only be seen as valid if you return a value that is considered true from your compareDates() function.  returning false or NULL will mean that firstPageEnterDate field is invalid.

Comment: I'm using cake framework for a couple of days, and didn´t yet checked the inner guts of it. The "call" happens here:   `'firstPageEnterDate' => array(
   'datetime' => array(
    'rule' => 'compareDates',` so, perhaps some trickery is happening on that "rules" interpretation, making this a false case to understand the return value?

Comment: ohh well the fact that you are using the cake framework is an important detail, let me update my answer with more information

Answer (score 1):

You do not even need the else since you do not do anything else if the if statement is false

You can just return true as the last statement in the function.

This allows you to check for truthyness from the return of the function otherwise if the if statement fails, your function will return undefined

It is all up to you what you return if the if statement is false, in this case you returned true

Answer (score 0):

Always have a return statement at the end :),you can also rewrite like so:

```
public function compareDates() 
{
  if ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] === "1") {
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];
  } 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Downvote care to explain? This may be syntactically or semantically incorrect, but the advice is sound.

Comment: The result will be the same of his code.. I mean, `return true;` will be called with and without `} else {`.. And no, i don't downvote you.

Comment: It was downvoted do to an error in judgement regerding the original answer( I edited it ), it has the same ideea: Always return a default and keep code cleaner :)

Comment: I usually try to avoid "dangling if statements" like this, as it's easier to read when there is an else (since it's guaranteed to be called anyway, and I don't think any PHP IDE would complain since it IS guaranteed) but a downvote on this with no comment is bad form IMHO

Answer (score 0):

something like would be clearer in my opinion.

```
public function compareDates() 
{
  return ($this->data[$this->alias]['enabled'] != "1")  ||

    ($this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageEnterDate'] < 
      $this->data[$this->alias]['firstPageLeaveDate'];)
}
```